# Why does the definition of ingratiate say "gain favor WITH somebody" instead of "FROM or FOR somebody"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, definition

> Ingratiate
>
> verb: gain favor with somebody by deliberate efforts
>
> Even though Tom didn't like his new boss, he decided to ingratiate himself to her in order to advance his career.

I find the meaning a little vague even after searching multiple sources.

My doubt is that we gain favor *from* someone not *with* someone by putting efforts. We do favor *for* someone not *with* someone.

What is the clear meaning of this word is still unclear to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can *do a favour for someone* (or *do someone a favour*), meaning basically "do something for them because you are kind". If I do a favour for you, I carry out some action because I want to do something kind for you.

Separately, one can *gain favour with someone*. I gain favour with you if you get a better opinion of me. Crucially, "I gain favour with you" indicates a change in *your* mental state, not an action I carry out.

I can try to gain favour with you - for example, by doing you a favour - but I can't guarantee it: I can only gain favour with you if your mental state changes, and I can't force your mental state to change.

I *ingratiate* myself with you if I do something with the specific aim of gaining favour with you.

Comment: Can I ask what is the meaning of favor in this sentence? I looked online and saw there are multiple meaning of favor. I think I am confused because I don't know how the word favor fits in the meaning. The only meaning I know is -an act of kindness beyond what is due or usual.
"I've come to ask you a favor"

Comment: In "gain favour with someone", the word "favour" doesn't mean "an act of kindness". It is more like the meaning "a condition of being regarded with approval or good will".